# How to add dropdown into AddEditDelete dynamically using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have add/delete/edit dynamically using `jQuery` and i wanted to put `dropdown` menu into a column. Is there possible ?

```js
function edit_row(no) {
  document.getElementById("edit_button" + no).style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("save_button" + no).style.display = "block";

  var component = document.getElementById("component_row" + no);
  var kra = document.getElementById("kra_row" + no);
  var kpi = document.getElementById("kpi_row" + no);
  var sfa = document.getElementById("sfa_row" + no);
  var target = document.getElementById("target_row" + no);
  var weightage = document.getElementById("weightage_row" + no);

  var component_data = component.innerHTML;
  var kra_data = kra.innerHTML;
  var kpi_data = kpi.innerHTML;
  var sfa_data = sfa.innerHTML;
  var target_data = target.innerHTML;
  var weightage_data = weightage.innerHTML;

  component.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='component_text" + no + "' value='" + component_data + "'>";
  kra.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='kra_text" + no + "' value='" + kra_data + "'>";
  kpi.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='kpi_text" + no + "' value='" + kpi_data + "'>";
  sfa.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='sfa_text" + no + "' value='" + sfa_data + "'>";
  target.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='target_text" + no + "' value='" + target_data + "'>";
  weightage.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='weightage_text" + no + "' value='" + weightage_data + "'>";
}

function save_row(no) {
  var component_val = document.getElementById("component_text" + no).value;
  var kra_val = document.getElementById("kra_text" + no).value;
  var kpi_val = document.getElementById("kpi_text" + no).value;
  var sfa_val = document.getElementById("sfa_text" + no).value;
  var target_val = document.getElementById("target_text" + no).value;
  var weightage_val = document.getElementById("weightage_text" + no).value;

  document.getElementById("component_row" + no).innerHTML = component_val;
  document.getElementById("kra_row" + no).innerHTML = kra_val;
  document.getElementById("kpi_row" + no).innerHTML = kpi_val;
  document.getElementById("sfa_row" + no).innerHTML = sfa_val;
  document.getElementById("target_row" + no).innerHTML = target_val;
  document.getElementById("weightage_row" + no).innerHTML = weightage_val;

  document.getElementById("edit_button" + no).style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("save_button" + no).style.display = "none";
}

function delete_row(no) {
  document.getElementById("row" + no + "").outerHTML = "";
}

function add_row() {
  var new_component = document.getElementById("new_component").value;
  var new_kra = document.getElementById("new_kra").value;
  var new_kpi = document.getElementById("new_kpi").value;
  var new_sfa = document.getElementById("new_sfa").value;
  var new_target = document.getElementById("new_target").value;
  var new_weightage = document.getElementById("new_weightage").value;

  var table = document.getElementById("data_table");
  var table_len = (table.rows.length) - 1;
  var row = table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML = "<tr id='row" + table_len + "'><td  id='component_row" + table_len + "'>" + new_component + "</td><td id='kra_row" + table_len + "'>" + new_kra + "</td><td id='kpi_row" + table_len + "'>" + new_kpi + "</td><td id='sfa_row" + table_len + "'>" + new_sfa + "</td><td id='target_row" + table_len + "'>" + new_target + "</td><td id='weightage_row" + table_len + "'>" + new_weightage + "</td><td><input type='button' id='edit_button" + table_len + "' value='Edit' class='edit' onclick='edit_row(" + table_len + ")'> <input type='button' id='save_button" + table_len + "' value='Save' class='save' onclick='save_row(" + table_len + ")'> <input type='button' value='Delete' class='delete' onclick='delete_row(" + table_len + ")'></td></tr>";

  document.getElementById("new_component").value = "";
  document.getElementById("new_kra").value = "";
  document.getElementById("new_kpi").value = "";
  document.getElementById("new_sfa").value = "";
  document.getElementById("new_target").value = "";
  document.getElementById("new_weightage").value = "";
}
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0 auto
}

th,
td {
  position: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  border-width: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <table align='center' cellspacing=2 cellpadding=5 id="data_table">

    <tr>
      <th>Component</th>
      <th>KRA</th>
      <th>KPI</th>
      <th>SFA</th>
      <th>Target</th>
      <th>Weightage %</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" id="new_component"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="new_kra"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="new_kpi"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="new_sfa"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="new_target"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="new_weightage"></td>
      <td style="border:0px;"><input type="button" class="add" onclick="add_row();" value="Add Row"></td>
    </tr>

  </table>
  </div>

</body>
```

So , i wanted to put `dropdown` on SFA when click Add Row button the new row will generate and also `dropmenu` on SFA will display. Basically i have tried input select option on `javascript` but when i click Add Row button there is like no function happen.

Comment: This looks like code that Reactjs like to do. Do you have a option to use somethig with more power than jQuery?

Comment: @JamesAMohler no sir, could you help me ?

Comment: SO is not code tutorial service. You can look up ReactJS here and on their website.